# Load Scrollview and tableView too slow

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios8, scrollview

I'm trying to create a scrollview with buttons inside 2500 that connects with a left table which scrolls together, these data must be passed taken from the json, I'm trying but I can not upload more than 15 seconds on iPhone on iOS 8, someone has some idea?

Comment: Are there data causing a huge memory usage?

Comment: yes, but the really problem that it is too slow to load, is there alternative ?

Comment: What is too slow to load?  Are you downloading JSON?  Parsing the JSON? Loading your table from the JSON data?  Are you trying to create 2500 cells in a UITableView?

Comment: I am tryingo to create a table that is connected to a scrollview and into scrollview 2500 button, 50 for each row

Comment: Instead of a scroll view, you might want to use a UICollection view for the buttons. You could do the whole thing with a single collection view, but you would have to write your own UICollectionViewLayout class.